# when custom gradle plugin, how to debug real gradle project

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy

With `ProjectBuilder` I can build a test project in:

```
ProjectBuilder.builder().withProjectDir(new File("path/to/dummy/android/app"))).build()
```

but when I invoke `p.getTasks()`, it returns empty. It's not true. The specific android project has many android tasks. I can't test `task.doFirst` and `task.doLast`, so how to fix it?